# SharePoint 2007 Wiki links broken and no breadcrumbs

Tags: wiki

We are currently using SharePoint 2007 at my company and we have discovered that a large number of our Wiki articles are now broken links (404 errors). I looked through the history list to see if they worked at previous points in time and I found that the links were still dead.

Also, when we create a new wiki article by editing the page and using the brackets [[ ]] it creates a link without breadcrumbs, which prevents us from creating the new article since clicking on it brings it right to a 404 error. However, if I create the new article at the top of the page it does usually work, just not anywhere else. No idea why.

We're just at a loss here and any help would be appreciated. I've searched Google extensively and have found basically nothing helpful, plus most help seems to be only for 2010 and 2013 since 2007 is so old (totally understandable). We plan to upgrade to 2013, but it is going to be a long time, so fixing this issue is important.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that when I changed the names of the articles in the main page edit mode it broke the links (the articles were still there in the system). Had to go into each article, change the title, copy the new title, and paste into the main page editor. Problem solved. Still don't have a resolution to the breadcrumb issue, but my boss thinks it's a problem in the HTML.